# Mysql Create Event Error Timestamp Interval

Tags: mysql

I want to create an event but

```
    $sorgu = $db->query("CREATE EVENT asd2a2s2d ON SCHEDULE every CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL 1 minute
DO
update player set gun=gun+$piece where id='$id' ");
         
       
        if($sorgu){
            echo "true";
        }else{
            echo"false";
        }
```

but CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL it works when you remove this part where is the problem
?

Comment: It would be helpful if you stripped out the programming language and just made it a mysql query, and told us what the corresponding error message is.

Comment: @AllanWind   how will I do?

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-event.html) says the schedule syntax is:

```
AT timestamp [+ INTERVAL interval] ...
| EVERY interval
| [STARTS timestamp [+ INTERVAL interval] ...]
| [ENDS timestamp [+ INTERVAL interval] ...]
```

so you probably want `STARTS CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL 1 minute` or in this case just `EVERY MINUTE`.

Comment: but  STARTS CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL 1 minute this is not working

Comment: Can you try with a hard-coded string instead of CURRENT_TIMESTAMP?